# Cannot convert from char to string

Tags: java

```
String org = "Welcome";
String rev = "";

for (int i = org.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    rev = rev+org.charAt(i);
}
System.out.println(rev);
```

What does this line mean?  `= rev+org.charAt(i);`

Comment: WHAT is the question about? Title: "*cannot convert from...*"  and body: "*what does this line means...*" do not match! || The `+` operator works as String Concatenation if one of the operands  is a `String`; the other operand will eventually be converted to `String`, if needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a statement to add to the variable `rev` the character in org at `i` position. Because you are doing this in a loop, it incrementally adds character in position `i`.

So iterations becomes :

```
rev = ""  + e --> resulting in e
rev = "e" + m --> resulting in em
rev = "em" + o --> resulting in emo
rev = "emo" + c --> resulting in emoc
rev = "emoc" + l --> resulting in emocl
rev = "emocl" + e --> resulting in emocle
rev = "emocl" + W --> resulting in emocleW
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     String org = "Welcome";
String rev = "";

for (int i = org.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    rev = rev+org.charAt(i);
}

first iteration --> rev = ""  + e -->  e
second iteration --> rev = "e" + m -->  em
third iteration -->  rev = "em" + o -->  emo
fourth iteration --> rev = "emo" + c --> emoc
fifth iteration -->  rev = "emoc" + l --> emocl
sixth iteration --> rev = "emocl" + e --> emocle
seventh iteration --> rev = "emocl" + W --> emocleW

final value of rev is - emocleW
```

Answer (score 0):

rev = rev+org would take the entire string "welcome" and concatenate it with rev (which is "") then assign that value to rev, but the .charAt(i) concatenates one character in the org variable at a time (the character that exists in the current position of i) and since the loop is being decremented it's taking the characters from the end of 'welcome' and adding it to the beginning of rev, reversing the string in org.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Above comment gives an clear understanding. But why it is mandatory to concatenate the rev + org

Answer (score 0):

Other Answers are correct.

### Code point

Let me add that this code uses the outmoded type `char` which has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.

Instead, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

As an alternative to [concatenating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) via the `+` (PLUS SIGN) operator, you may choose to call [`String#concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)). Same effect, choose according to your tastes.

```java
String org = "Welcome";
String rev = "";

int[] codePoints = org.codePoints().toArray() ;
for ( int index = codePoints.length()-1 ; index >= 0 ; index -- ) {
    int codePoint = codePoints[ index ]
    String s = Character.toString( codePoint );
    rev = rev.concat( s );  // ⬅️  String#concat does the same job as + (PLUS SIGN) operator… concatenates strings.

}
System.out.println(rev);
```

### `StringBuilder`

Even better would be use of a class deigned for building up longer strings: [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Use of that class *may* be more efficient in some versions of Java. More importantly, it expresses your intention to accumulate characters into a longer string.

```java
String org = "Welcome";
String rev;

int[] codePoints = org.codePoints().toArray() ;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder() ;
for ( int index = codePoints.length()-1 ; index >= 0 ; index -- ) {
    int codePoint = codePoints[ index ]
    sb.appendCodePoint( codePoint ) ;

}
rev = sb.toString() ;
System.out.println(rev);
```

### `SequencedCollection#reversed`

[Java 21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_21)+ gained the new feature of [sequenced collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431). `List` now offers a [`reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#reversed()) method which produces a view onto the original list but with an encounter order that goes in reverse. As a view onto the original, this method works even on an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable).

If we make a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) from our stream of code points, we can call `reversed` instead of the complicated `for` loop seen above.

A `List` must contain objects rather than primitive values. So we call [`IntStream#boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()) to wrap each `int` code point as a [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) object.

We collect those code points in reverse by using a `StringBuilder`, similar to section above.

The resulting code is a one-liner:

```java
String rev =
        "Welcome"
                .codePoints ( )
                .boxed ( )
                .toList ( )
                .reversed ( )
                .stream ( )
                .collect ( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString ( );
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"Cannot convert from char to string ..."*

Use the *[String#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char))* method.

```java
String s = String.valueOf('a');
```

> *"... What does this line mean?  `= rev+org.charAt(i);` ..."*

This is appending *org.charAt(i)* to *rev*.

You can also prepend the value.

```java
for (char c : org.toCharArray()) rev = c + rev;
```

Or, use the *[StringBuilder#reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse())* method.

```java
String rev = new StringBuilder(org).reverse().toString();
```